# uninitialized constant when running rspec test with concerns used in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When I run `rspec spec/models/football_match_spec.rb` I get an `uninitialized constant` error:

```
/Users/jamessmith/project/app/models/football_match.rb:3:in `<class:FootballMatch>': uninitialized constant FootballMatch::Type1Fixture (NameError)     
from /Users/jamessmith/project/app/models/football_match.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'     
from /Users/jamessmith/project/spec/models/football_match_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'   
from /Users/jamessmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `load'    
from /Users/jamessmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `block in load_spec_files'    
from /Users/jamessmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `each'    
from /Users/jamessmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `load_spec_files'     
from /Users/jamessmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'    
from /Users/jamessmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'  
from /Users/jamessmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'  
from /Users/jamessmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'   
from /Users/jamessmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'     
from /Users/jamessmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rspec:23:in `load'  from /Users/jamessmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'    
from /Users/jamessmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'  
from /Users/jamessmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Type1Fixture concern:

```
module Type1Fixture
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def competitors
    [competitor_1, competitor_2]
  end

  def competitor_1_score
    [fhhts || 0, shhts || 0, ethts || 0].reduce(:+)
  end

  def competitor_2_score
    [fhats || 0, shats || 0, etats || 0].reduce(:+)
  end

  def name_with_scores
    if [Fixture::IN_PROGRESS_STATUS, Fixture::COMPLETED_STATUS].include?(status)
      "#{competitor_1.name} #{home_team_score} - #{away_team_score} #{competitor_2.name}"
    else
      "#{competitor_1.name} vs #{competitor_2.name}"
    end
  end
end
```

Edited FootballMatch model:

```
class FootballMatch < Fixture
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Type1Fixture
end
```

I've added `app/models/concerns` to the `config.autoload_paths` array in `environments/test.rb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be caused by not having the correct file name. For `Type1Fixture`, the file containing the class should be called `app/models/concerns/type1_fixture.rb`. Is this the case?

Comment: Bloody hell. That was exactly it. I was thrown off the scent because I guess Rails was autoloading everything in the concerns folder with wild disregard for filenames.
Thanks, Matt.